# Zendesk API - Creating a ticket gives wrong ticket status

Tags: rest, post, curl, http-post, zendesk

Zendesk API documentation states that when creating a ticket through the API, the `status` field can be set to "new" (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets#create-ticket), yet if I call the API with the following command specifying a value for `status`, it creates a token yet still sets `status` to be the default value of `open`:

```
curl -u <username>/token:<api_token> https://<subdomain>.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json -d '{"ticket": {"subject":"test subject", "comment": { "body": "test body" }, "status": "new" } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v POST
```

The relevant part of the response body is:

`"ticket": {
    "url": "https://<subdomain>.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/60.json",
    "id": 60,
    "external_id": null,
    "via": {
      "channel": "api",
      "source": {
        "from": {},
        "to": {},
        "rel": null
      }
    },
    "created_at": "2016-05-05T13:30:01Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-05T13:30:01Z",
    "type": null,
    "subject": "test subject",
    "raw_subject": "test subject",
    "description": "test body",
    "priority": null,
    "status": "open",
    "recipient": null,
    "requester_id": 5917202647,
    "submitter_id": 5917202647,
    "assignee_id": 5917202647,
    "organization_id": 3740197137,
    "group_id": 28473587,
    "collaborator_ids": [],
    "forum_topic_id": null,
    "problem_id": null,
    "has_incidents": false,
    "due_at": null,
    "tags": [],
    "custom_fields": [],
    "satisfaction_rating": null,
    "sharing_agreement_ids": [],
    "fields": [],
    "brand_id": 1090897,
    "allow_channelback": false
  }`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that if you assign a ticket to a group with only one member/agent, the ticket automatically gets assigned to that lone agent. As such, any ticket that's already assigned to a specific agent, is automatically set to open instead of new.

Because I was using a test subdomain, I was the only agent and so it was auto-updating the status from "new" to "open".

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I made the same API call (with my creds/subdomain) and it worked, setting the "status" to any option I choose (new, pending, solved).

Have you confirmed that all your credentials and subdomain are correctly inputted? Also, check the API settings in your Zendesk account. Try creating a new token and  Save the settings.

If the API token still doesn't work, maybe try authenticating with password or making the request by means other than curl.

Comment: I solved the issue with a Zendesk support ticket but thanks for your tips, upvoted.